# Is there a way to configure the "factory-method" attribute using annotations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj

I'm currently setting up `AspectJ` in a java project. In order to have the `@Value` and `@Autowired` attributes in my `AuditingAspect.aj` class properly instanciated, I have an `ApplicationContext.xml` file in which I declare the `.aj` class as a Bean with a factory-method="aspectOf" attribute.

I wanted to know if it was possible to set this factory-method attribute using an annotation because, in the project, all the beans are declared using annotations. I created the ApplicationContext.xml only for that aspectJ bean and it bothers me, but I can't find a way to do it using annotations.

I tried to do it with a java configuration class, but I have the following error :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile
>   (default-compile) on project virtualprinter-queue: Compilation
>   failure: Compilation failure:
>
> [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/avangrunderbe/Documents/Oniryx/virtualprinter-c/virtualprinter-queue/src/main/java/be/fgov/minfin/virtualprinter/VirtualPrinterQueueConfig.java:[3,45]
>   cannot find symbol
>
> [ERROR] symbol:   class AuditingAspect
>
> [ERROR] location: package be.fgov.minfin.virtualprinter.aspects
>   VirtualPrinterQueueConfig.class

AuditingAspect.aj

```
public aspect AuditingAspect {
    @Value("${auditlog.request.logged_by}")
    private  String AUDIT_LOG_REQUEST_LOGGED_BY;

    @Value("${auditlog.request.ressource}")
    private  String AUDIT_LOG_REQUEST_RESOURCE;

    @Value("${auditlog.endpoint}")
    private  String AUDIT_LOG_ENDPOINT;

    @Value("${auditlog.user}")
    private  String AUDIT_LOG_USER;

    @Value("${auditlog.password}")
    private  String AUDIT_LOG_PASSWORD;

    @Autowired
    private AuditLogger auditLogger;
    (...)
}
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="auditingAspect"
          class="be.fgov.minfin.virtualprinter.aspects.AuditingAspect"
          factory-method="aspectOf"/>
</beans>
```

VirtualPrinterQueueConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class VirtualPrinterQueueConfig {
    @Bean
    public AuditingAspect getAuditingAspect(){
        return new AuditingAspect();
    }
}
```

PS : Sorry for my English, it isn't my native language.